# Groups where every continuous function is uniformly continuous

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, topological-groups, uniform-continuity, topological-vector-spaces

Let $G$ be a topological group, and $(X, d)$ a metric space. The function $f : G \to X$ is *left uniformly continuous* if for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an identity neighbourhood $U$ such that for all $g\in G, u \in U$ it holds $d(f(g), f(ug)) < \varepsilon$.

If $G$ is compact or discrete, every continuous function is uniformly continuous. Is there a larger class of groups for which this holds, maybe with some extra assumptions on $X$ or $f$? I am particularly interested in totally disconnected locally compact groups $G$, ultrametric normed vector spaces $X$ and bounded functions $f$.

Comment: Your definition of uniform continuity is missing $f$ in both arguments of $d$.

Comment: @MaoWao thanks I edited it